# Predict function in forecast.holtwinters function

Tags: r, forecasting

I am looking at `forecast` package `HoltWinters` method code from [this link](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/master/R/forecast2.R) (for code understanding purpose). I couldn't find which "R" source file has this `predict` function defined in to look at source code. Can some one please help me on how can trace this function to a specific source code file?

```
 pred <- predict(object,n.ahead=h,prediction.interval=TRUE,level=level[1]/100)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exported, but you can find it using the `:::` operator:

```
forecast:::predict.HoltWinters
# function (object, n.ahead = 1, newxreg = NULL, se.fit = TRUE, ...)
#   ....
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I am using HoltWinters, not ARIMA, will it still call predict.Arima? I am confused sorry!

Comment: @Nambari See `?forecast::forecast.HoltWinters` (the function the line in question resides in). The documentation clearly states that the function calls `predict.HoltWinters` and even hyperlinks to the documentation for that function (in the stats package).

Comment: @joran: Thanks! After few minutes of research figured it. I have used methods(forecast) and then documentation helped me to nail down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
forecast<- HoltWinters(datatimeseries, beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE)



>forecast:-

Holt-Winters exponential smoothing without trend and without seasonal component.

Call:
HoltWinters(x = datatimeseries, beta = FALSE, gamma = FALSE)

Smoothing parameters:
 alpha: 0.02412151
 beta : FALSE
 gamma: FALSE

Coefficients:
      [,1]
a 24.67819
```

Try this, It works for me...